# app crashes in device but not in emulator

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I ran the app on the emulator, it's working fine, but when i install it in the device it crashes.

here's the code that is responsible for the crash

```
c1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ( c1.isChecked() )
                {
                    SQLHandler check = new SQLHandler(StartMoving.this);
                    check.open();
                    check.updateTodo(currentMove, "sortandpurge", "Done");
                    check.close();
                }else{
                    SQLHandler check = new SQLHandler(StartMoving.this);
                    check.open();
                    check.updateTodo(currentMove, "sortandpurge", "Not Done");
                    check.close();
                }
            }
        });
```

what this code does is that if the checkbox is clicked the database will be updated.

```
public void updateTodo(String todoMove, String todoName, String todoValue){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(todoName, todoValue);
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE4, cv, KEY_TODOMOVE + "='" + todoMove + "'", null);
    }
```

but somehow the app crashes in the device but not in the emulator

here's the log cat

```
09-27 02:59:05.743: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:05.763: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-27 02:59:08.153: D/dalvikvm(1130): GC_CONCURRENT freed 44K, 2% free 10692K/10823K, paused 11ms+10ms
09-27 02:59:08.213: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:08.343: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-27 02:59:08.724: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:08.853: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-27 02:59:09.223: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:09.353: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-27 02:59:09.403: D/dalvikvm(1130): GC_CONCURRENT freed 13K, 2% free 11222K/11335K, paused 6ms+7ms
09-27 02:59:09.723: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:09.763: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-27 02:59:10.243: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:10.293: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-27 02:59:10.733: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:10.863: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-27 02:59:11.234: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:11.353: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-27 02:59:11.743: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:11.863: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-27 02:59:12.233: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:12.363: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-27 02:59:12.723: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:12.803: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-27 02:59:13.233: I/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-27 02:59:13.363: I/dalvikvm(1130): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Can you please post the LogCat output as well?

Comment: The logcat output does not have enough information about the crash. Can you please filter the log on warning level and post it? Specifically, look for log statements for your application package.

Comment: that's because it does crash in the emulator, just the device

Comment: I think it has something to do with updating from the database, because when I change the database update to a toast its working fine in the device.

Comment: Yes, but irrespective of whether the application crashes in emulator or device, the log statement should be generated. If you cannot get the log statements, run the application in debug mode, creating a breakpoint at where you think the problem is and step through to locate the actual error.

Comment: @Rajesh I found the problem, it seems that i set one of the Columns as integer and not as text as it should be, stupid me, how can i still reward you if you didn't place any answer?

Comment: Glad that you found the issue. You can mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it seems that i set one of the Columns as integer and not as text as it should be, stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

When an ANR (Application Not Responding) condition happens, dalvik will send the "threadid=3: reacting to signal 3" message. You can find details in the /data/anr/trace.txt file.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up